# ¿Porque no me re compila correctamente mi app en visual studio 2015? no encuentra .dll

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ide, compilador

Cuando quiero recompilar mi app para que me tomes cambios recientes que quizas no haya tomado con la simple modificacion, me salen los siguientes errores:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error CS0006  Metadata file 'C:\Users\Ned-Design\Documents\projects\NederaV4\Ned4DataAccess\bin\Debug\Ned4DataAccess.dll'
> could not be found    Ned4Business    C:\Users\Ned-Design\Documents\projects\NederaV4\Ned4Business\CSC    1   Active

Salen cada vez que quiero recompilar mi aplicación y copio los archivos de la carpeta de otro proyecto en esa ubicación pero aun así sigue sin funcionar y no se a que se deba eso, si se supones que es parte del IDE y no de mi código

Comment: Los errores y codigo sea texto es mas facil para pruebas y para leer

Answer (score 1):

En algún lugar de tu código usas alguna herramienta de esos paquetes en ocaciones se dañan las referencias tienes que volver a importar las referencias a los dll, no basta con copiarlos, en tu proyecto en el visual studio le puedes dar click derecho al proyecto y le dan en referencias, busca los dll que te están marcado y le das importar

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/f3st0d45(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

A mi me ha pasado y el problema consistía en que tenía incompatibilidades entre las versiones del Framework: el proyecto WEB con la versión 4.5, mientras que un helper generador de PDFs con la versión 4.7.2.
Luego de igualar las versiones el problema se corrigió.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Primero trata de traer la referencia del proyecto desde el explorador de soluciones, luego cuando ya la tengas en tu proyecto, debes decirle en las propiedades de la referencia (Click derecho)que es **Copy Local**= **True**.